# GAS script to monitor email inbox only responds intermittently

Tags: email, triggers, google-apps-script

I have created Google App Script that triggers every 15 minutes and monitors an inbox label for new messages. The label is applied by a email filter that only labels emails when they come from a specific email address and specific subject. When the script runs it:

1. Checks to see if there are any messages with that label
2. Grabs the body of the email
3. Splits the sentences in the at the `"<br />"`
4. Pastes the resulting Array into a spreadsheet
5. Removes the inbox label so that it is no longer in the inbox.

The problem I am having is that the script does not paste anything to the spreadsheet when it runs, it skips that and just removes the label. If I manually go in and add the label back onto the message, the next time the script runs it behaves perfectly adding all the array elements to the spreadsheet and then removing the label. But I don't want to have to reapply the label every time. I am new to scripting, so I apologize if my code is not to accepted standards.

```
function myFunction() {

//Get Email and split data into array
var NewPhy = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("New Physician Request")
var TransPhy = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("Transferred Physician Request")
var Threads = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("New Physician Request").getThreads();
if (Threads.length > 0) {
    var messages = Threads[0].getMessages()
    var body = messages[(messages.length - 1)].getBody().split("<br />")

    //Search, tag, and import values into spreadsheet
    var Spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(" Spreadsheet URL here ");
    var Sheet = Spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Sheet Name here").insertRowBefore(3);

    var SiteElement = ArrayLib.find(body, -1, "Associated Customer Site Information:")
    var Site = body[SiteElement + 1].replace(/[A-Z]{3}/gm, "").replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/igm, "").replace(/^[ \t]+/igm, "").replace(/&lt;/igm, "").replace(/&gt;/igm, "").replace(/&nbsp;/igm, "").replace(/&quot;/igm, "").trim()
    var A3 = Sheet.getRange("A3").setValue(Site).setBorder(true, false, false, false, false, false).setBackgroundRGB(239, 239, 239);
    var ConsultantElement = ArrayLib.find(body, -1, "Marketing Consultant 1 =")
    var Consultant = body[ConsultantElement].replace("Marketing Consultant 1 =", "").replace(/[A-Z]{3}/gm, "").replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/igm, "").replace(/^[ \t]+/igm, "").replace(/&lt;/igm, "").replace(/&gt;/igm, "").replace(/&nbsp;/igm, "").replace(/&quot;/igm, "").replace(/^[ \t]+/, "").trim()
    var C3 = Sheet.getRange("C3").setValue(Consultant).setBorder(true, false, false, false, false, false);

// Remove inbox label and add Transferred label
    TransPhy.addToThread(Threads[0])
    NewPhy.removeFromThread(Threads[0])
}
```

Comment: I think the problem is in the place where you are splitting by the `<br>` tag. Can you log the contents of the email before splitting. Emails from the same source can have different line breaks depending how the email client behaves. So, if you can log the email content that will be useful

Comment: I might be useful to use the new GMailMessage.getPlainBody() method and then use sting manipulation.  This will strip the HTML from the message body and make is easier to manipulate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@patt0 - I had tried the .getPlainBody() option but it didnt help. It turned out that the problem wasnt in how the script parsed the data, it was in the initial 'if' statement. I changed the first four lines to this and it fixed it:

```
var NewPhy = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("New Physician Request")
var TransPhy = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("Transferred Physician Request")
var Threads = NewPhy.getThreads()
if (Threads[0]) {  
        var messages = Threads[0].getMessages()
        var body = messages[0].getBody().split("<br />")
```

After this, I left the rest of the code as it appears in the initial question and it works. For anyone that might need an example like this in the future, this code triggers every 5 minutes and monitors a google inbox for an email that contains a form letter, then parses the data out of that form letter and adds it to a spreadsheet.